# file contents are cleared on node restart

Tags: arrays, node.js, file-io

I have a function that writes an array of objects to file.

```
save() {
    const getCircularReplacer = () => {
      const seen = new WeakSet();
      return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
          if (seen.has(value)) {
            return;
          }
          seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
      };
    };

    const newState = JSON.stringify(this.tasks, getCircularReplacer());
    const newStateHash = hash.h32(newState, 0xABCD).toString(16);

    if (newStateHash !== this._previousStateHash) {
      fs.writeFileSync('./.persistance.json', newState);
      this._previousStateHash = newStateHash;
    }
  }
```

The callback in done from within another function with `setInterval()`.

```
 setInterval(() => {
      this.save();
    }, 1000);
```

The idea behind this is, in case node process crashes after restart it reads the data from the file and performs some actions based on that data. The function runs normally and saved data to file, if I kill the node process the file retains the data, but as soon I restart the program the contents of the file are gone.

I assume this might be because of default mode on `writeFileSync()`, how can I prevent the behaviour where file contents are erased on restart?

Do I need to add a delay to function call or use append instead of write?

Comment: Are there any tasks when you start the app? I mean what is the value of `this.tasks` when you save it the first time after starting the app?

Comment: The idea is to let the tasks continue running and reattach to them after restart. The tasks are running either in docker container or as detached shell process. The initial value of `this.tasks` is blank after restart, the file contents are used to reinitialise the class. [Here](https://pastebin.com/V3bV1EeU) are the file contents if it helps.